# Get ControlToValidate Property From CustomValidator in Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, customvalidator

I want to get the ControlToValidate Property From Code Behind, here is my aspx.

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="custtxtTest" OnServerValidate="custtxtTest_ServerValidate" ControlToValidate="txtTest" ForeColor="Red" Text="*" />
```

In my Code behind I want to get the property "ControlToValidate", but this doesn't seem to be a valid property of source:

```
 protected void custtxtTest_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
    string test = source.ControlToValidate;
    }
```

I checked [Asp.Net custom validator: how to get the 'controlToValidate' property on ClientValidationFunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636228/asp-net-custom-validator-how-to-get-the-controltovalidate-property-on-clientv) but that is only for a client function, not in code behind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
var validator = (source as CustomValidator);
string controlToValidate = validator.ControlToValidate;            
TextBox txt = validator.NamingContainer.FindControl(controlToValidate) as TextBox;
```

Regards,
Uros