# Gridview Custom Validator cannot set innerHTML after returning from ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, gridview

I would like to validate a gridview column when inserting to prevent duplicates.  The grid has paging so I have to go to the database to check all of the values in this field.  Upon return, if the value exists, I would like to set the Error message to 'UserID exists'.

My problem is when the `WebMethod` returns with the results, I do not have access to the parameters, `sender` or `args`.  The value is null when I set an alert in the `success` function.

Is this the best way to validate for duplicates when you have to go back to the database?  If so, how can I save the `sender` and `args` parameters so the custom validation is triggered.

This is my markup:

```
<div id="UsersGridWrapper" runat="server">  
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelUserData" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:GridView ID="UserInfoGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="15">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserID">
            <HeaderTemplate> UserID
                 <asp:ImageButton ID="senigvUserIDFilter" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/filter.png" OnClientClick="return ShowHideFilterTxtBox('senigvTxtUserIDFilter')" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="senigvTxtUserIDFilter" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" style="display:none;" ClientIDMode="Static" OnTextChanged="senigvGridFilter_TextChanged">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="senigvLblUserID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>' ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>   
                <asp:Label ID="senigvLblEditUserID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>' ></asp:Label>                
            </EditItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="senigvTxtBxInsertUserID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>      
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="senigvRequiredFieldInsertUserID" ControlToValidate="senigvTxtBxInsertUserID" runat="server"
                    ErrorMessage="Required field." ValidationGroup="InsertSenderValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>            
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="senigvMaxValInsertUserID" ControlToValidate="senigvTxtBxInsertUserID" runat="server"
                    ErrorMessage="Maximumn length is 40." ValidationGroup="InsertSenderValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error"
                    ValidationExpression="^.{1,40}$" >
                </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="senigvCustomInsertUserID" ControlToValidate="senigvTxtBxInsertUserID" runat="server" 
                    ValidationGroup="InsertSenderValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error"
                    ErrorMessage="*" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateUserID" EnableClientScript="true">
                </asp:CustomValidator>
             </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>          
    </Columns>     
</asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

This is the jquery function that is called during custom validation:

```
function ValidateUserID(sender, args) {
var EnteredUserID = args.Value;
//Call to database to check if UserID exists
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "EditUsers.aspx/DoesUserIDExist",
    data: JSON.stringify({ strUserID: EnteredUserID }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (data, sender, args) {
        if (data.d == true) {
            args.IsValid = false;
            sender.innerHTML = "UserID exists.";
        }
        else {
            args.IsValid = true;
            sender.innerHTML = "";
        }
        return;
    },
    error: function (exception, sender, args) {
        args.IsValid = false;
        sender.innerHTML = "";
        $("#senigvTxtBxInsertUserID").val("");
        alert('An error occurred while calculating the message length: ' + exception.toString());
    }
});
};
```

The C# method that is called from jquery function to validate existence of UserID:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static bool DoesUserIDExist(string strUserID)
{
    bool tbUserIDExist = false;

    PagingService.PagingClient tpagingClient = new PagingService.PagingClient();
    string tstrXmlTableData = tpagingClient.CheckUserID(strUserID);
    DataTable tdtUserID = CommonMethods.ParseXML(tstrXmlTableData);
    if ((tdtUserID != null) && (tdtUserID.Rows.Count > 0))
    {
        string tstrUserID = tdtUserID.Rows[0]["UserID"].ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tstrUserID))
        {
            tbUserIDExist = true;
        }
    }
    return tbUserIDExist;
}
```

The jquery function is called and correctly determines if the UserID exists in the database or not.

My problem is that in the `success` function, the `sender` object is null. How can I save this before I go to the database?
Or is there a better approach to check for existence?

Comment: have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636228/asp-net-custom-validator-how-to-get-the-controltovalidate-property-on-clientv

Comment: that is not my problem.  I can identify the sender before I make the .ajax call.  When it comes back from the server, `sender` and `args` are null.  I tried saving the `sender and `args` objects in a variable before the ajax call so in the success function, i can set the `IsValid` and `innerHTML` attributes but that does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work.  In case anyone else needs to do client validation and make a database call to the server..
1.  Added a variable to the function to save the results of the server call method
2.  Used the variable to set the `args.IsValid` function.
3.  Did not need to set the innerHTML.  Set the error message in the markup.  It is displayed if `isValid` is false.
Final Markup:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="senigvCustomInsertUserID" ControlToValidate="senigvTxtBxInsertUserID" runat="server" 
                        ValidationGroup="InsertSenderValidation" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="message-error"
                        ErrorMessage="UserID exists." ClientValidationFunction="ValidateUserID"  ValidateEmptyText="false" EnableClientScript="true">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Final jquery function:

```
function ValidateUserID(sender, args) {
        var EnteredUserID = args.Value;
        var isValid;

        //Call to database to check if UserID exists
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "EditUsers.aspx/DoesUserIDExist",
            data: JSON.stringify({ strUserID: EnteredUserID }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                isValid = data.d;
            },
            error: function (exception) {
                $("#senigvTxtBxInsertUserID").val("");
                alert('An error occurred while calculating the message length: ' + exception.toString());
            }
        });
        args.IsValid = isValid;
    };
```

Server Method call remained the same.
The boolean returned if valid was set to true; if not valid set to false.